# How to sum up votes of the songs with Collectors.summarizingInt and flatMap operators usage

Tags: java, mongodb, functional-programming, java-stream, spring-webflux

Let's say that I have classes that illustrate the problem of songs and votes voted for.

User.java

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

  @Id private String id;

  private String username;

  private String email;

  private Integer age;

  private String password;

  @DBRef(db = "interview", lazy = true)
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ToString.Exclude
  private Set<Song> songs;
}
```

Song.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Song {

  @Id private String id;

  private String title;

  private String author;

  private String songGenre;

  Set<Vote> votesOfSong;
}
```

Vote.java

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "votes")
@Getter
public class Vote {

  @Id private String id;

  private User user;

  private Song song;

  private VoteKind voteKind;

  @Default private LocalDateTime dateOfVote = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

and

VoteKind.java

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum VoteKind {
  LIKE(1),
  DISLIKE(-1);

  private final Integer voteValue;
}
```

I want to create a `Flux` method which will find x of the highest-rated songs overall.

So far I have not completed method:

```
public Flux<Vote> findHighestRatedSongs(int numberOfTopSongs) {

    return songRepository.findAll()
                         .limitRate(numberOfTopSongs)
                         .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(value -> value.getVotesOfSong()
     .stream()
     .flatMap(vote -> vote.getVoteKind()
                          .getVoteValue(), ...missing expression))))
}
```

As far as I understand I should use `toMap` method like:

```
Mono<Map<Set<Vote>, Song>> collect = songRepository.findAll()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Song::getVotesOfSong, Function.identity()));
```

after all flat `getVotesOfSong` with `flatMap` operator to `VoteKinds` and at the end`reduce` result by summing likes and dislikes but I have a problem with final syntax which make me stuck. 
All I want to return is `Flux<Map<String, Integer>>` which will match `SongTitle` and a number of votes for a particular song.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to reach a desirable goal.

Comment: i would suggest storing the votes in its own table and count the votes in that repository, instead of trying to derive the top voted songs through the songsrepository. And when you have the top votes, you get the songs through the top 10 votes.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the concept of `Flux`, the core of using `Stream` here would look like the following(comments inlined.)

```
Stream<Song> songCollection = songRepository.findAll();

Map<String, Integer> songTitleToVotes = songCollection
        // create a song to its total vote Map
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), this::getSumOfVotes))
        // stream the entries of this map
        .entrySet().stream()
        // sort them in descending order of votes
        .sorted(Map.Entry.<Song,Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
        // then limit the top N songs
        .limit(numberOfTopSongs)
        // collect these N songs while mapping song to its title
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().getId(), Map.Entry::getValue,
                (a, b) -> a, // check for duplicate title when using this
                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

where the `getSumOfVotes` method could be implemented as

```
private int getSumOfVotes(Song song) {
    return song.getVotesOfSong()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(vote -> vote.getVoteKind().getVoteValue())
            .sum();
}
```